# フォーム内でスペースキーで空白のみを入力してエンターキーを押すとクラッシュする

Tags: c#

C#で、URLのみが機能する入力フォームを作っています。

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text)) {
    wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
}
```

上記コードの機能は、

・ユーザーが任意のURLを入力してエンターキーを押すと、画面に該当ページが表示される。
・ユーザーが未入力の状態でエンターキーを押すと、入力が無効の扱いになる。

これらは正しい判定です。

しかし、問題として **ユーザーがスペースキーで空白のみを入力した状態で、エンターキーを押すと強制終了してしまいます。**
下記コードでは `IsNullOrEmpty` を使用していますが、フォーム欄に空白のみの入力がある場合、エンターキーは無効にならず決定され、クラッシュします。

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text))
```

ユーザーが未入力状態でエンターキーを押した際と、ユーザーがスペースキーで空白のみを入力してエンターキーを押した際に、エンターキーが無効になるコーディングはありませんでしょうか？

Comment: デバッグモードビルドしてデバッグ実行させてどこかで例外が発生しているとか調べてみましたか？ それらの状況を追記してみてください。

Comment: @kunif
無事解決しました。助言くださいましてありがとうございます。

Comment: 質問に対して「解決しました」だけだと、このスレッドにたどり着いた第三者にとって悲しいことになるので、〇〇というコードで例外が出ていたので△△に修正することで解決できた…といった回答をご自身で投稿していただけませんか？

Answer (score 1):

自己解決されたようですが、以下のように変更されたものと思われます。

> ユーザーが未入力状態でエンターキーを押した際と、ユーザーがスペースキーで余白のみを入力してエンターキーを押した際に、エンターキーが無効になるコーディングはありませんでしょうか？

こちらでデバッグ実行すると、

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUrl.Text))
```

こちらの行で「ハンドルされていない例外　System.ArgumentException: '値が有効な範囲にありません。'」となります。

```
    wbSample.Navigate(txtUrl.Text);
```

判定に使用するメソッドを`String.IsNullOrEmpty`から`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`に変えれば望み通りの動作になるでしょう。

```
if (e.Key == Key.Enter && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUrl.Text))
```

[String.IsNullOrEmpty(String) メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=net-6.0)

> 指定された文字列が`null`または空の文字列 ("") であるかどうかを示します。

[String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String) メソッド](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=net-6.0)

> 指定された文字列が`null`または空であるか、空白文字だけで構成されているかどうかを示します。

---

質問では問題の箇所だけがピンポイントで提示されていますが、問題の再現・調査・修正確認のためには、例えば以下の記事の概要やTutorialを基に作業できます。

[Microsoft Edge WebView2 の概要](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/)
[WinForms アプリでの WebView2 の使用を開始する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms)

上記TutorialのTextBoxである`addressBar`の`KeyDown`イベントに質問のコードを貼り付け、以下のようにTutorialの内容に合わせて調整します。
それで問題の再現と調査、修正確認が出来るようになります。

```
private void addressBar_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // 問題再現時: if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(addressBar.Text))
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(addressBar.Text)) // 修正版
    {
        webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(addressBar.Text);
    }
}
```